# Could not override the umask value for AWS Session Manager ssm-user

Tags: linux, bash, aws, umask, amazon-linux

Currently when I connect to an EC2 instance through SSM from AWS console it connects with default user : ssm-user. The umask value for this user is 022. I am trying to update the default umask value to 077. So, whenever I connect through SSM and run the umask command it should display 077. I want other users to have the same umask value.

I have tried the below changes. However, when I connect with SSM the user ssm-user has still has umask value as 022.

Ensured that umask value is 077 in the below files

```
/etc/bashrc
/etc/profile
/etc/login.defs
```

The ssm-user home directory has below files which has command to source the /etc/bashrc. However it looks like these files are not invoked.

```
.bashrc 
.bash_profile
```

Please help.